# Getting error in styles when moving to API Level 28

Tags: android

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  E:\location\Projects\app name\24-09-18\appname\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:5983: error: style attribute 'attr/textColorError (aka package.name:attr/textColorError)' not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\location\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\798b117930d6897772b9b2de605984ea\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        I:\Android-SDK\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\location\Projects\appname\24-09-18\appname\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\location\Projects\app.name\24-09-18\appname\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\location\Projects\app.name\24-09-18\appname\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\location\Projects\app.name\24-09-18\appname\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        package.name\
        -0\
        apk\
        -c\
        en\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\location\Projects\app.name\24-09-18\appname\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your values/attrs.xml:

```
<attr name="textColorError" type="color|reference"/>
```